# Spring Data JPA on JBoss EAP 6.1 - org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

Tags: java, spring, jboss, ejb, spring-data

I'm using in a part of my application EJB 3.1 (on JBoss EAP 6.1) with spring data JPA, using JPA repository.

However, I have a trouble on save and delete actions. In the delete, sometimes I have no error, but the object is not deleted. When I have the stack trace, looks like this:

```
10:10:04,710 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 2) JBAS014134: A Invocação EJB falhou no atendenteServiceBean do componente para o public abstract void br.com.gjccorp.service.support.GenericServiceRemote.delete(br.com.gjccorp.model.support.BaseEntityDTO) throws br.com.gjccorp.exception.ServiceException do método: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.handleException(BMTInterceptor.java:78) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.checkStatelessDone(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:56) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:94) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:329) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:70) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:203) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:898) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241) [spring-orm.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete(SimpleJpaRepository.java:148) [spring-data-jpa.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358) [spring-data-commons.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343) [spring-data-commons.jar:]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) [spring-tx.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) [spring-tx.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) [spring-tx.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92) [spring-data-jpa.jar:]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.delete(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.gjccorp.service.support.GenericServiceRemoteImpl.delete(GenericServiceRemoteImpl.java:78) [cartela-daqui-server-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:128) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 106 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "atendentes_senha_key"
  Detalhe: Key (senha)=(7342) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 108 more
```

I also tested removing the constraint and I don't have any errors, but the object is not removed.

On finds actions, with or without pagination, and the save action (persist), works fine.

On save (merge) I have the followed error:

```
10:00:35,790 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 3) JBAS014134: A Invocação EJB falhou no atendenteServiceBean do componente para o public abstract br.com.gjccorp.model.support.BaseEntityDTO br.com.gjccorp.service.support.GenericServiceRemote.save(br.com.gjccorp.model.support.BaseEntityDTO) throws br.com.gjccorp.exception.ServiceException do método: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.handleException(BMTInterceptor.java:78) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.checkStatelessDone(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:56) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:94) [jboss-as-weld-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1413) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1329) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:898) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241) [spring-orm.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.merge(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.gjccorp.repository.support.CustomRepositoryImpl.save(CustomRepositoryImpl.java:40) [cartela-daqui-data.jar:]
    at br.com.gjccorp.repository.support.CustomRepositoryImpl.save(CustomRepositoryImpl.java:1) [cartela-daqui-data.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358) [spring-data-commons.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343) [spring-data-commons.jar:]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) [spring-tx.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) [spring-tx.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) [spring-tx.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92) [spring-data-jpa.jar:]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) [spring-aop.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.save(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.gjccorp.service.support.GenericServiceRemoteImpl.save(GenericServiceRemoteImpl.java:60) [cartela-daqui-server-ejb.jar:]
    at br.com.gjccorp.service.remote.bean.AtendenteServiceBean.save(AtendenteServiceBean.java:53) [cartela-daqui-server-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [br.com.gjccorp.model.Atendente#1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:913) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:897) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:901) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 88 more
```

My application context for data looks like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="emf" jndi-name="${jta.emf.jndi}" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />

<bean id="tx" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.gjccorp.repository,br.com.gjccorp.repository.support" transaction-manager-ref="tx"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" factory-class="br.com.gjccorp.repository.support.CustomRepositoryFactoryBean" />
```

And my persistence unit looks like this, with more properties:

ALL
        ${jta.data.source.jndi}

My **beanRefContext.xml** on EJB module look likes that:

```
<bean id="app.context" lazy-init="true" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:/applicationContext.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

So, how to ensure the object on only one transaction? I have tried many type of propagation and nothing.

P.S: I use the same CustomRepository on other application, deployed on a web container (e.g.: Tomcat) without any trouble or error, with similar configuration, but using **JpaTransactionManager** instead **JtaTransactionManager**, **LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean** instead JNDI lookup, etc.

I try the configuration below using EJB, same error:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator" />

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<util:properties id="jpaProperties" location="classpath:hibernate.properties" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="${jta.data.source.jndi}" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaProperties-ref="jpaProperties" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.gjccorp.repository,br.com.gjccorp.repository.support" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" factory-class="br.com.gjccorp.repository.support.CustomRepositoryFactoryBean" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve by myself, shortly after. The problem isn't in the configuration, but a field in JPA entity annotated with @Version.

Removing the annotation and managing the version manually was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This has likely nothing to do with Spring JPA. @Version introduces optimistic concurrency controls, which prevents two processes from overwriting each other's edits on an object. An article on the subject can be found [here](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2012/11/02/version-based-optimistic-concurrency-control-in-jpahibernate/)